# Get data values from QuerySelectField with query_factory

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have problem to save data from QuerySelectField with query_factory. I will always end with:

**Error message**

```
InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) 
Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. 
[SQL: u'INSERT INTO asset_objects (asset_name, asset_type, asset_owner)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'd', u'Process', <__main__.Model_New_Users 
object at 0x03819A50>)]
```

**DB Model**

```
# --- New Information Assets ---
class Model_New_Asset(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'asset_objects'
id = db.Column('asset_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
asset_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False, index=True)
asset_type = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False, index=True)
asset_owner = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False, index=True)

def __init__(self, asset_name, asset_type, asset_owner):
    self.asset_name = asset_name
    self.asset_type = asset_type
    self.asset_owner = asset_owner
```

**Form**

```
class Form_New_Asset(Form):
    asset_name = StringField(u'Asset')
    asset_type = SelectField(u'Asset type', 
                             choices=[('Process', 'Process'),
                                      ('Information', 'Information'),
                                      ('Informationssystem', 'Informationssystem'),
                                      ('Applikation', 'Applikation')])
    # From Model_New_Users
    asset_owner = QuerySelectField(u'Owner',
                                   query_factory=lambda: Model_New_Users.query.all(),
                                   get_label='owner_name')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**Route**

```
@app.route('/add_asset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_asset():
    form = Form_New_Asset()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['asset_name'] or not request.form['asset_type']:
            flash(u'Fill out all fields...', 'error')
        else:
            add_data = Model_New_Asset(asset_name=form.asset_name.data,
                                       asset_type=form.asset_type.data,
                                       asset_owner=form.asset_owner.data)
           db.session.add(add_data)
           db.session.commit()
           flash('Post saved', 'info')
 ...
```

It seems that I can't retrieve the actual data from the query_factory function (asset_owner)?

Appreciate your assistance/help!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get an instance back is because you haven't given a

`def __str__():`

representation. Hope this help's newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're providing an instance of `Model_New_Users` as the 2nd (0-indexed) parameter.

```
InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) 
Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. 
[SQL: u'INSERT INTO asset_objects (asset_name, asset_type, asset_owner)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'd', u'Process', <__main__.Model_New_Users object at 0x03819A50>)]
```

But in your model you've defined it as a `String` type:

```
asset_owner = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False, index=True)
```

This is queried via a lambda in your form:

```
asset_owner = QuerySelectField(u'Owner',
                               query_factory=lambda: Model_New_Users.query.all(),
                               get_label='owner_name')
```

And then the *entire object* is passed in your update. I think this is the bug.

```
        add_data = Model_New_Asset(asset_name=form.asset_name.data,
                                   asset_type=form.asset_type.data,
                                   asset_owner=form.asset_owner.data)
```

I think you can fix it by specifying which field on the `Model_New_Users` you intend to pass. Something like `form.asset_owner.data.owner_name` or whatever.