# Python QuerySelectField and request.form returning dict key, not dict value

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I am not a programmer yet (working on it - this is my first big project), so sorry for the messy-ugly code.

I have some issues using `QuerySelectField` and `request.form['form_field_name']` to pull data from a SQlite table and to put it in another table.

I am trying to get data from the `name` column in the `Post` model to fill the `actual_amount_name` column in the `ActualPost` model, but I think I am actually pulling dictionary keys.

These are the 2 models/tables I am using:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='planned')
    category = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default=None)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    planned_amount_month = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    date_period = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}, '{self.category}'\
        , '{self.name}', '{self.planned_amount_month}'\
        , '{self.date_period}', '{self.comments}')"

#the function below queries the above model and passes the data to the QuerySelectField
def db_query():
    return Post.query

class ActualPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='actual')
    category = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default=)
    actual_amount_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    actual_amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ActualPost('{self.title}, '{self.category}'\
        , '{self.actual_amount_name}', '{self.actual_amount}'\
        , '{self.date_posted}', '{self.comments}')"
```

Now the `forms`:

In the `Post` model I have a column called `name`. The data in this filed is added by the user using WTForms (the `name` field in the class below):

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = HiddenField('Please enter the monthly Planned Amount details below:'\
           ,default='planned')
    category = SelectField('Category', choices=[('savings', 'Savings')\
               ,('income', 'Income'), ('expenses', 'Expense')]\
               ,validators=[DataRequired()])
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    planned_amount_per_month = FloatField('Planned Amount'\
                               ,validators=[DataRequired()])
    date_period = DateField('Planned Month', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    comments = TextAreaField('Comments (optional)')
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

In the `ActualPost` model I have a column called `actual_amount_name` and I want to fill the data in it by using a WTForm QuerySelectField, which queries the `name` in the `Post` model:

```
class PostActualForm(FlaskForm):
    title = HiddenField('Please enter the Actual Amount details below:', default='actual')
    category = SelectField('Category', choices=[('savings', 'Savings')\
               ,('income', 'Income'), ('expenses', 'Expense')]\
               ,validators=[DataRequired()])
    actual_amount_name = QuerySelectField('Name', query_factory=db_query\
                         ,allow_blank=False, get_label='name')
    actual_amount = FloatField('Actual Amount', validators=[DataRequired()])
    date_posted = DateField('Date of actual amount', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    comments = TextAreaField('Comments (optional)')
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

This is the route that takes the passes the `name` data from one model to the other:

```
@posts.route("/post/new_actual", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_actual_post():
    form = PostActualForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        actualpost = ActualPost(title=form.title.data\ 
                    ,category=form.category.data\
                    ,actual_amount_name=request.form['actual_amount_name']\
                    ,actual_amount=form.actual_amount.data\ 
                    ,date_posted=form.date_posted.data\
                    ,comments=form.comments.data\
                    ,actual_author=current_user)
        db.session.add(actualpost)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.actual'))
    return render_template('create_actual_post.html', title='Actual',
                           form=form, legend='New Actual Amount')
```

The issue I have, is that instead of the `name` being transferred over:

[image: name that I want transferred over]

I think that the dictionary key is being transferred and I see a number:

[image: what I actually got]

I have been battling this for 3 days and I am fairly certain that QuerySelectField is the culprit.

I have tried other ways of calling the form, like `actual_amount_name=request.actual_amount_name.data` which errors-out with

> `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>`

I have also tried multiple other ways, including `get`, [from this documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/). I have also tried to query the database and to use the SelectField, instead of QuerySelectField, but no luck until now.

I am using the latest versions of Python, Flask, SQLAlchemy, etc, and I am using Pycharm as an IDE

**Edit:**

Based on the comments received below (thank you all!) I went over the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887519/how-to-use-queryselectfield-in-flask)

I have removed `.all()` from the function `query_db` in my models (edited above as well)

Retried, using `actual_amount_name=request.form['actual_amount_name']` in the route and I got the same result (dict key instead of name)

Modified the route to `actual_amount_name=form.actual_amount_name.data` and I added a bit of code to write the output of the route to a txt file:

```
actualpost = ActualPost(title=form.title.data, category=form.category.data\
                , actual_amount_name=form.actual_amount_name.data\
                , actual_amount=form.actual_amount.data, date_posted=form.date_posted.data\
                , comments=form.comments.data, actual_author=current_user)
    text = open("C:/Users/Ato/Desktop/Proiect Buget/actual_post_test_1.txt", "a")
    text.write(str(actualpost))
    text.close()
    db.session.add(actualpost)
    db.session.commit()
```

The data being written to the txt file contains the correct `actual_amount_name` (Spook - my cat's name):

> `ActualPost('actual, 'expenses'        , 'Post('planned, 'expenses'        , 'Spook', '123.0'        , '2018-05-22 00:00:00', '')', '26.5'        , '2018-05-22', 'testul 19')`

But I get the debugger error:

> `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>`

Comment: Learning to code is a great start. Now you have some code you have written that isn't working right. That is, it compiles but does not run as expected, or issues errors. Even better! This is your opportunity to learn what is arguably the _most important skill a coder will ever learn_: debugging. Folks here will want to see what you have done to dig into the guesses you have shared with us. See here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: first thing you need if you doubt about a value : print it. If you're not sure about the result  of `request.form['actual_amount_name']`, just print it or use a debugger to pause the program  in your function. Then did you give a look at these answers ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887519/how-to-use-queryselectfield-in-flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use QuerySelectField in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887519/how-to-use-queryselectfield-in-flask)

Comment: thank you all for the pointers,

Comment: I have looked over the question and answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887519/how-to-use-queryselectfield-in-flask.  I have removed the `.all()` from the db_query function in models. Leaving `request.form['actual_amount_name']` in the route has in the same behavior (dict key in `actual_amount_name`). I modified the route to `request.actual_amount_name.data` and I have added code to write a txt file to see what is being passed over, and the data in it looks correct (name instead of dict key). But the debugger fails with `<unprintable InterfaceError object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!!!

while poking some more around StackOverflow, I stumbled [over this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396127/get-data-values-from-queryselectfield-with-query-factory) and the answer provided to it by the user ACV.

So, all I needed to do was, in my route, to add `.name` at the end of `actual_amount_name=form.actual_amount_name.data`, like so:

> **`actual_amount_name=form.actual_amount_name.data.name`**

This is what my web page table looks like now:

[image]

And this is the output in the text file:

> `ActualPost('actual, 'expenses'        , 'Spook', '26.5'        , '2018-05-22', 'God dammit' aaaargh#&*^$lkjsdfho')`